# Calculating distance between to points of a triangle using pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I'm writing a program, where you input triangle point coordinates, the program checks if the triangle exists and outputs the area of the triangle. I have to use pointers in the program.

```
class Vertex
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Vertex(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    float getDistance(Vertex *anotherVertex)
    {
        float dist;
        int tempx = 0, tempy = 0;
        tempx = anotherVertex->getX();
        tempy = anotherVertex->getY();
        dist = ((tempx - x) * (tempx - x) + (tempy - y) * (tempy - y));
        return dist;
    }

    void setCoord(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
};

class Triangle
{
private:
    Vertex *a, *b, *c;
public:
    Triangle()
    {
        a = new Vertex(0, 0);
        b = new Vertex(0, 0);
        c = new Vertex(0, 0);
    }

    void Set_coord()
    {
        int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
        cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2 >> x3 >> y3;
        a->setCoord(x1, y1);
        b->setCoord(x2, y2);
        c->setCoord(x3, y3);
    }

    bool existTriangle() {
        float ab = a->getDistance(b);
        float bc = b->getDistance(c);
        float ca = c->getDistance(a);
        if (ab + bc > ca && ab + ca > bc && bc + ca > ab) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    float getArea() {
        float p;
        float ab = a->getDistance(b);
        float bc = b->getDistance(c);
        float ca = c->getDistance(a);
        p = (ab + bc + ca) / 2;

        return sqrt(p * ((p - ab)*(p - bc)*(p - ca)));
    }
};
```

I'm struggling to make the getDistance function working as I'm inexperienced with using pointers, when debugging i'm getting this error in the getX() function.

Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was 0xDDDDDDDD.

EDIT:

here is my main()

```
int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    vector<Triangle*> vertices;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Triangle* newVertices = new Triangle();
        newVertices->Set_coord();
        vertices.push_back(newVertices);
        delete newVertices;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (vertices[i]->existTriangle())
        {
            cout << vertices[i]->getArea();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a minimal example (a `main()` where you use your classes).

Comment: How do you call `getDistance`? Also, there seems to miss a square root call in its implementation.

Comment: I added my main() to the post, also thanks for pointing out that it's missing a square root, I call getDistance in the Triangle class

Comment: `vertices.push_back(newVertices); delete newVertices;` - you just turned the pointer you pushed into the vector into a dangling pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your main function ( that's why I asked you to post it:) ):

```
Triangle* newVertices = new Triangle();
vertices.push_back(newVertices);
delete newVertices;
```

You dynamically allocate memory, that is pointed to by `newVertices`.
You store the pointer into the vector.
You delete the memory pointed by `newVertices`.

As a result, now that pointer is a dangling pointer.

So, you must not delete `newVertices` into the loop.

Do your thing (computer areas, check it a triangle exists, etc.), and then, when you are done, start deleting your dynamically allocating memory...